# How to use screen sharing option using agora sdk for ios

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, agora.io, screensharing

I am using following example of Agora latest sdk to share screen on my 2 devices :
https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples/tree/master/iOS

All option like video calling etc are working fine but when i open screen sharing option channel is connect successfully but there is no option to share screen only both devices share camera video ie video call is connected .Is there any solution that can make this sdk work and share screen ?

Answer (score 1):

check out this guide for getting video and screen sharing working on your iOS device:

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_ios?platform=iOS